# I own a Ford Focus 2.0 tdci mk2 facelift model. Nearside rear wheel making strange noise

Tags: disk-brakes

I've just had both rear wheels brake pads and discs  along with a rear offside caliper replaced. The mechanics kept my car for 5 days and I picked her up last night just before I went to work. I drove home the following morning and as I slowed down not far from my house, I heard this noise that sounded like something had caught in my rear nearside wheel and was rubbing against the spokes on my rim. So I stopped the car got out and using a torch I had a look. Couldn't see anything wrong. Got back in the car and the noise started as I accelerated but grew quiet as I increased speed. If I go round corners the noise is the same as low speed. If I brake the noise stops.

I phoned my mechanic but he took a half day so I went to a local mechanic and he checked the car out. He thinks that the brake pads are knocking each other when not engaged but on inspection and test drive he said it was safe to drive. tbh I'm a bit nervous to drive my car. 
Also last month I had my rear shocks replaced. 
Any information or advice is most welcome...

Update:
Spoke to a few work friends and played them the recording I made earlier and one of them said that it sounded like what happened to his car. So I asked what the outcome was and he said the mechanic told him the brake pads were inserted incorrectly by the previous garage? Is this correct? 
Pity I can't add an audio clip.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to Friday night and went online to a website called fixmycar.com and entered my details and issue with the car. Got a few quotes and the next morning a mechanic phoned me up and told me he could diagnose the problem for £50 but parts and labour would be extra. Plus he'd come to me. So arranged a time that suited us both and he met me at work at 21:20 on Saturday. Within 10 minutes he had the wheel off and caliper and found the problem. The brake pads were inserted incorrectly. He corrected the problem, cleaned everything up, put the caliper on and the wheel. Took it for a test run and problem solved. Asked him what the total was and he said £50 all inclusive. A bit taken aback as I was expecting to pay £100. Not going back to previous mechanic.

Comment: Thanks so much for the follow-up and I'm happy it was so easily solved. Yah, stupid mechanics sometimes do stupid things. £50 and he met you at work? Sounds like you got a steal of a deal! +1 for the answer. Set it to "the answer" by using the checkmark below the voting on your answer.